# group_map with each column one by one without mapply

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                 size = sample(1:100, 6),
                 length = sample(10:30, 6))
```

I want to calculate a mean value for each group using each column but `group_map` doesn't treat columns one by one. I want to avoid excessive using of nested mapply functions.

Comment: `df |> summarize(across(size:length, mean), .by = group)`?

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: What is your expected output and what does "it doesn't work mean?" Did you get an error, or was the output different from your expectation, and if so how?

Comment: `.by` was added in dplyr v1.1.0 in late 2022, btw. For earlier versions, you could use `df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(across(size:length, mean)) %>% ungroup()`

Comment: The last answer works, thanks! The first one gave NA values and the result didn't literally make any sense.

Comment: Once you update dplyr (I find the `.by` syntax super helpful) the output will be identical.